# .getAbsoultePath prints the ProjectPath instead of SystemPath?

Tags: java, file, path

There is a little Problem with the `file.getAbsolutePath()` method and I tried also the `f.getcanonicalPath();` method.

Instead of

> C:/Documents and Settings

it prints

> C:\Users\me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fileC\Documents and Settings

Could you maybe explain how it should be changed ?

Thank you

```
    f = new File(C://);
    fs = f.list();

    for(String fsv : fs) {
     f = new File(fsv);
     String ap = f.getAbsolutePath();
     System.out.println(ap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It taked a bit time and I still try to understand more about, but I found something that may work as well.

Except an accessDeniedException it works. And in java8 the code seems more shorter.

If someone have an answer for the first code it will be great too.

Thanks

```
  Path p = Paths.get("C://");
FileVisitor<Path> fv = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
      throws IOException {
    System.out.println(file);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }
};

try {
  Files.walkFileTree(p, fv);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or for java 8

```
try {
Files.walk(Paths.get("C://")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); }

Answer (score 1):

In `fs` are only the names of the files in `C:` and if you give the file name to the File Object you add the name to your current working directory.
You could change the code like that:

```
    File f = new File("C:/");
    File[] fs = f.listFiles();
    for (File fsv : fs) {
        String ap = fsv.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(ap);
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to run with your code, but I get just "C:/" ? I thought to format the string in the former code, but maybe there is some better code.

Comment: Maybe the printed String depends on in which folder the Code is running. Nontheless I can't test well as the String in the IDE is wrong. Perhaps the method "newDirectoryStream()" frrom the class "Files" might help, but I should read more about.